# Change package identifier of libGDX game

Tags: android, libgdx, package, android-manifest

I have an existing game in google play store. The existing version was developed fully using Android Studio using native codes. Now I am about to release a highly enhanced version of the same game in play store, but this time, the application is developed using `libGDX`. The problem is my application's original package name was `com.myname.mygame`(some confidentiality issues in revealing the real name). I gave the same package name for `libGDX` base project. But when it is compiling in android, it is adding a `.android` extension to the package name. So the package name now becomes `com.myname.mygame.android`, due to which I can't release the app as an update. What can I do to change the package name?

**EDIT**

As per one of the answers posted here, I tried changing the package name of core module `fromcom.myname.mygame` to `com.myname.mygame.core`, then changed package in manifest to `package="com.myname.mygame"` and moved AndroidLauncher from `com.myname.mygame.android` to `com.myname.mygame`. But now I am getting the following error when I try to run the app:

```
Installing com.myname.mygame.android
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.myname.mygame.android"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.myname.mygame.android
Success


Launching application: com.myname.mygame.android/com.myname.mygame.AndroidLauncher.
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am start -n "com.myname.mygame.android/com.myname.mygame.AndroidLauncher" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.myname.mygame.android/com.myname.mygame.AndroidLauncher }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.myname.mygame.android/com.myname.mygame.AndroidLauncher} does not exist.
```

I noted that it is still written there are `com.myname.mygame.android` and the application fails to launch.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks a lot to Saeed's answer, I was able to do it, but there was one more thing I needed to do for making the app to work after changing the package name. I am explaining the steps here:

1. Change package name of core module from `com.myname.mygame` to `com.myname.mygame.core`
2. Change package in manifest to `package="com.myname.mygame"`
3. Move AndroidLauncher from `com.myname.mygame.android` to `com.myname.mygame`

The above steps solved the problem of changing the package name, a big thanks to Saeed. Now the application was failing to launch. Then I saw that the installation command was wrong. To change this, just go to the android application's `build.gradle` and change the following line:

```
commandLine "$adb", 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-n', 'com.myname.mygame.android/com.myname.mygame.android.AndroidLauncher'
```

to:

```
commandLine "$adb", 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-n', 'com.myname.mygame/com.myname.mygame.AndroidLauncher'
```

And you are ready to go!!!

Answer (score 6):

Libgdx has this architecture :

`com.myname.mygame` as core module

`com.myname.mygame.android` as android module

`com.myname.mygame.desktop` as desktop module ,etc.

So you need to refactor them for example change  package name of core module from`com.myname.mygame` to `com.myname.mygame.core` then change package in manifest to `package="com.myname.mygame"` and move `AndroidLauncher` from `com.myname.mygame.android` to `com.myname.mygame`

Comment: Can you tell me how to refactor core module and change package name in android studio?

Comment: Right click on core folder -> refactor -> rename